# Unable to instal MySQL on to my Debian 7 with puTTY

Tags: php, mysql, debian

I've been searching through the internet trying to find answers to this all morning but everytime I find a solution, it seems to bring up another problem that a previous solution should have fixed. I seem to be going round and round at the moment. And some help would be appreciated.

I am setting up a MySQL Database on my OVH VPS which is running Debian 7 by using puTTY. It's all relatively new to me since I only bought the server yesterday morning but as I've tried to setup MySQL and phpMyAdmin I've ran in to some problems. I've followed several tutorials, and asked a friend who has also setup his own OVH MySQL Database.

These are the two main tutorials I've been following:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-7

I seem to be doing fine until I get up to the point when I actually need to install the MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

When I run this, it asks my password then installs it. However, at the end it print this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Firstly to solve this, I tried to install mysql-server-5.5 (since that is what it says it depends on). However, it then says mysql-server-5.5 depends on something else, and that something else depends on something else and so on.

It keeps repeating this until I get to 'libc6', which I then install using the same command

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

But this time, it prints a long error

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Setting up phpmyadmin (4:3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by       another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing phpmyadmin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It was talking about locked files so I did another Google search and came to this

https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

However its suggestion was to remove the locked file with the command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

However, it said it should only be used as a last resort so I decided not to do it. Anyway, the original MySQL setup tutorial I was following didn't mention anything about installing all these dependencies, therefore I went back to the error I got when I first did 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server'

(Here's the original error again)

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I pretty much just pasted the whole thing in to Google search and found this result

https://askubuntu.com/questions/489815/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependicies

The first answer was talking about removing and changing the version of MySQl (this solution didn't apply to me) so I tried the second solution which was to use the command 'sudo aptitude install mysql-server'. I did this and returned a similar error to before about the locked files

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up phpmyadmin (4:3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing phpmyadmin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

So now, I've realised I've screwed something up. So how can I unlock this file so I can install the other items? I didn't quite understand and wasn't confident using the post about unlocking locked files so how would I use it in my situation?

I've concluded that I've messed something up whilst setting up phpMyAdmin and MySQL since the error message contains something about that. And my overall question is how can I unlock these files? And then install the MySQL stuff correctly? Because right now, I've not installed something right...

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thankyou so much in advance

Comment: try with "sudo apt-get -f install" .
you can also try with "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade"

Comment: @Scream What is the command supposed to do? And it returns with an error code saying that: 'debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable'  So how can I use 'sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock' to unlock this issue?

Comment: you can find a solution [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: @Scream Ok, I've been able to use 'sudo apt-get -f install', thankyou for the help. But I've been continuing on with this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu    And under the sub heading 'Step 2 - Installing MySQL' I've run in to a problem. It says I need to activate MySQL using the command 'sudo mysql_install_db' but the command isn't recognized? Haven't I installed MySQL now?

Comment: try with "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart"

Comment: ubuntu is not debian so some commands are different or not present.
Usually I install a LAMP server on debian in one command: "apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin"

Comment: @Scream Sorry to keep bugging you, but 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart' didn't work for some reason. Neither did 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade' as you suggested earlier. Is this part of a bigger problem or something? Also, just another question, what exactly does 'sudo apt-get -f install' do? Just to improve my understanding. Thanks

Comment: -f option as --fix-broken , try with "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install"

Comment: @Scream MySQL commands still don't work. I tool a look in the file at /etc/init.d/mysql and noticed there was nothing inside. Is that normal?

Comment: No, is not normal. try with "sudo dpkg --reconfigure mysql-server"

Comment: I don't even have MySQL installed yet, since it says ' no package named `mysql-server' is installed' when I run 'sudo dpkg --configure mysql-server'. Going back to my original problem in my post, it says 'The following packages have unmet dependencies: [...]' when installing. How can I fix that firstly? Thanks

Comment: I find [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/526693/how-to-reinstall-broken-mysql-package) solution

Comment: @Scream I took a longer look around Google this time and found a person who had the exact same problem as me: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189227    Someone who replied to his post noted that it was a bug and it has been reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbi-perl/+bug/1254144    However, it doesn't say where I can fix the bug on the website? Any ideas?